# How to turn off image overlays for mobile phone (CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am a student trying to turn off the image overlays when my site is a mobile size. When you hover over images at 1280px, there's text. Instead of the image overlays, I want paragraphs to show up when in mobile view. The problem is, the paragraphs show up at full screen laptop width and not mobile view.  In my html I have included a  under each container for the mobile view paragraphs.

My HTML:

```html
<section class="flex-container"> 

<div class="containertwo">    
    <img src="../assets/Lifestylewriting.png" alt="Avatar" class="image"> <p class="description"> LIFESTYLE WRITING </p>
  <div class="overlaytwo">
    <div class="portfolioText">I wrote this article about being able to spend time with yourself.</div> 
  </div>
    </div>
    <p class="responsiveportfolioText"> I wrote this article about being able to spend time with yourself. </p>
</section>
```

```css
.container,.containerthree {
 
position: relative;
  
width: 23%;

}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  right: 0;

  height: 90%;

  width: 100%;

  opacity: 0;

  transition: .5s ease;

  background-color: beige;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;

.responsiveflex-container{

    display:none;

    visibility:hidden;

}

.responsiveportfolioText{

visibility:hidden;

display:none;

color:white;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 450px)

.portfolioText{

visibility:  hidden;
}
    
    .overlay, .overlaytwo, .overlayfour, .overlaythree{
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
.containertwo:hover .overlaytwo, .container:hover .overlay , .containerfour:hover .overlayfour{
    
opacity:0;

visibility: hidden;

.responsiveportfolioText{

        visibility: visible;

        text-align:left;

        font-size: .5em;

        font-weight:400;

        display: flex;

        color:black;
}

.responsiveflex-container{

    display: flex;

    visibility:visible;
}

.portfolioText{

visibility:  hidden;

}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you implemented media queries yet?

Comment: Try `display: none ` for hover if you want hide something.

Example if you want disappear `<div class="something">some text here</div>` on hover you do it like this: `.something:hover { display: none; }` and then you hide it on hovering.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container,.containerthree {
 
position: relative;
  
width: 23%;

}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  right: 0;

  height: 90%;

  width: 100%;

  opacity: 0;

  transition: .5s ease;

  background-color: beige;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;

.responsiveflex-container{

    display:none;

    visibility:hidden;

}

.responsiveportfolioText{

visibility:hidden;

display:none;

color:white;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 450px){

.portfolioText{

display:  none;
}
    
    .overlay, .overlaytwo, .overlayfour, .overlaythree{
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
.containertwo:hover .overlaytwo, .container:hover .overlay , .containerfour:hover .overlayfour{
    
opacity:0;

display: none;}

.responsiveportfolioText{

        display: none;

        text-align:left;

        font-size: .5em;

        font-weight:400;

        display: flex;

        color:black;
}

.responsiveflex-container{

    display: flex;

    visibility:visible;
}

   
    
}
```

you didn't wrap media query styling in a curly brace plus `display:none` is preferable to `visibility:hidden`.
you can copy paste my code or look closely for the edit.

Comment: Setting my all the container hovers to display: none worked for the mobile display. However, now the image overlays are not showing at 1280px.  I will try to figure out why my code is fighting. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px)

.portfolioText{

visibility:  hidden;
}
    
    .overlay, .overlaytwo, .overlayfour, .overlaythree{
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
.containertwo:hover .overlaytwo, .container:hover .overlay , .containerfour:hover .overlayfour{
    
opacity:0;

visibility: hidden;

.responsiveportfolioText{

        visibility: visible;

        text-align:left;

        font-size: .5em;

        font-weight:400;

        display: flex;

        color:black;
}

.responsiveflex-container{

    display: flex;

    visibility:visible;
}

.portfolioText{

visibility:  hidden;

}
```

If you want to hide something use `display: none` instead `visibility: hidden`, then you can hide it. You also missing some {} marks be careful with them. I need close tags also, not just starting tag.

Comment: you have a few fundemental coding issues with your code. 1st, largest smartphonescreens are  480px. Plently are larger then 450px. 2nd, you css code is invalid. Media quereis need to be opened with `{` and clsoe with `}` which you forgot to do. 3rd, your  css would only work for the media queries then. Media queires that change something needs to below the actual css to change it as otherwise the normal code will oevrwrite the media queries as they read last.